# Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 doesn't see my Bluetooth adapter

Tags: bluetooth, 16.10

I want to use my Bluetooth speaker, but I couldn't enable Bluetooth. Screenshot from settings

[image]

Windows says that it's a Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth adapter

```
$rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
$lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Unex DHXA-225 [105b:e044]
```

### Kernel driver in use: ath9k

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Sony Corporation RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [104d:90ab]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169

$lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:02d3 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e036 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    1.858929] usb 1-1.2: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   13.637679] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   13.637693] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.637696] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.637698] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.637702] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  144.460384] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  144.460388] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  144.460398] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

$lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             552960  10 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm

$modinfo ath3k | grep vermagic
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'ath3k': No such file or directory

$uname -a; grep [[:alnum:]] /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep ath3k
Linux SomeUbuntuPC 4.8.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 11 14:03:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ dmesg | grep ath3k

$ dkms status
btusb-lp1542743, 0.1: added
```

Comment: Windows says that it's a Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth adapter

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; lsmod | grep blue`

Comment: Does `sudo modprobe ath3k` result in any change?

Comment: @Jeremy31 it's doesn't help :(

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath3k': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Comment: Have you installed anything else to attempt to fix this?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, I reinstalled bluez

Comment: @Jeremy31 I remembered what I used $sudo apt-get purge bluez

Comment: Please add the results for `modinfo ath3k | grep vermagic; uname -a; grep [[:alnum:]] /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep ath3k`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Done this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49455/discussion-between-jeremy31-and-david).